# Why would link_to URL parameter not function properly with symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a html.erb (called show.html.erb) that is displaying a post, I am adding a link_to in order to edit the post. There is only one line of change that I did

**does not work**

```
<%= link_to("edit", "/posts/:id/edit") %>
```

**works**

```
<%= link_to("edit", "/posts/#{@post.id}/edit") %>
```

For routes.rb, I have

```
get "posts/:id/edit => "posts#edit"
```

In the Controller,

```
  def edit
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
```

in the edit.html.erb, I have

```
<textarea><%= @post.content %></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="save">
```

> NoMethodError in Posts#edit
>
> Showing /home/progate/tweet_app/app/views/posts/edit.html.erb where line #6 raised:
>
> undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass

With my limited knowledge of Rails, I understand that because in the controller, I am defining @post with find_by, I would imagine that link URL can be using symbol :id.

But it seems like that is not the case.

Why does link_to with :id not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
Because the first 'link_to' is literally taking you to 'www.yoursite.com/posts/:id/edit' while the second one uses something called "String Interpolation" to replace the #{} block with the ruby code inside of it. In this case, the proper Post ID taking you to 'www.yoursite.com/posts/1/edit' or whatever the id of the post is.

Long Answer:
When you created the route

```
get "posts/:id/edit => "posts#edit"
```

That ":id" is just a stand in for something else and becomes a parameter, so when you make a link_to using string literals ("/posts/:id/edit") it takes you to edit a post with an ID of ":id";

```
 <%= link_to("edit", "/posts/:id/edit") %>
```

The second one works because it uses String Interpolation to inject the ID of the post into the link_to;

```
 <%= link_to("edit", "/posts/#{@post.id}/edit") %>
```

becomes;

```
<%= link_to("edit", "/posts/1/edit") %>
```

and then finds a post with an ID of 1 and edits it.

The reason you are getting the error is because in the first one with no interpolation, it's not finding a Post, so `post.content` can't work since post is nil.